# preloaded link font filename is uglified/hashed and causes mismatch

Tags: webpack, filenames, webpack-dev-server, preload

I'm facing a strange problem with webpack dev server, where a font served statically from my public folder via a link preload head tag is getting uglified/hashed in its filename.

In my @font-face declaration, however, this hashing isn't happing and thus there is a mismatch causing the browser to not be able to match the preloaded font with the one used later.

This is the preloaded link tag inside my index.html file:

```
<link rel="preload" href="../public/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
```

This is the @font-face declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.woff2') format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

(These imports both work, even though the paths slightly differ. For some reason, the path for the link tag needs the 'public' folder name in it, the font-face one doesn't.)

I'm running my dev server via webpack-dev-server.

Now, for some reason, the preloaded font is served as "http://localhost:8080/5f724b831a87738ee6ca.woff2" when I look in the network tab. And a second font is served for the font-face declaration but this time in its normal non-uglified filename: "http://localhost:8080/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.woff2".

Hence there is a mismatch and I get a console warning in Chrome that the preloaded font isn't used within a few seconds.

How can I prevent webpack-dev-server from serving the font with a hashed filename in the preload case?

The index.html that contains that preload link tag is used in my webpack config like this:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: './index.html'
  })
]
```

I've read through a lot of webpack docs related to static file serving of the devServer but couldn't find anything related to filename hashing. It's currently a complete mystery to me why my preloaded link tag is getting hashed and what's causing it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!